# Where to store user credentials when using fingerprint authentication in Android

Tags: android, security, authentication, fingerprint

As the title suggests, i'm making an app that allows the user to login using fingerprint authentication. The problem i'm having is where to store the credentials they submit?

The flow would be -> User logs in first time with credentials -> enable fingerprint auth and store these credentials -> Validate fingerprint then access stored credentials.

I thought of using `SharedPreferences` but if the device is rooted these are easily accessible.

So where is the safest and most secure place to store these credentials to avoid them being accessed outside of the app?

EDIT:

I'm using this wrapper to handle the fingerprint authentication 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4493

Comment: Refer this link for better use of Fingerprint authentication http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial#Accessing_the_Android_Keystore_and_KeyGenerator

Comment: I would suggest to use the [AndroidKeystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#WorkingWithKeyStoreEntries) for storing the encryption keys. The keys from this store can be "linked" to a fingerprint authentication (see section "Requiring User Authentication For Key Use" on the linked page).

Answer (score 1):

I use this library: https://github.com/JesusM/FingerprintManager. What I do is after the user sign in I take the user name and password and combine them into 1 string username:password, Then I encrypt this using the library. Next time user sign in into the app I decrypt it using this library.